# Accessing variables of Activity on Callback in Android

Tags: android, callback, native

I want to access a global variable which is initialized in OnCreate through a callback which is returned.

The complications :

1. The callbacks are from native c++ code, so I pass in an object of the activity in initialize function so that the C++ code callback the Java code. This works perfectly fine as I am able to log when my Java method is called from C++
2. Now when I get the callback from C++ code, I try to call a method of an object named pc.(PeerConnection). But now when the callback is received pc is always null, thus throwing a null pointer exception.

I think it is due to the fact that the instance of the Activity I pass and the instance where pc is initialized are different, I even tried passing context/activity instance to C++ code but that doesn't work  either.

Any ideas on what I may be doing wrong?

Here is my Activity code :

```
   @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            initialize(new MainActivity());   // This is native function which takes the object name

            PeerConnectionFactory factory = new PeerConnectionFactory();
            MediaConstraints pcConstraints = sdpMediaConstraints;
            pcConstraints.optional.add(
            new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("RtpDataChannels", "true"));
            pcConstraints.optional.add(
            new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement", "true"));

            pc = factory.createPeerConnection(iceServers, pcConstraints, pcObserver); // This is where pc is assigned 

       }

       //Callback from the C++ code
       public void onConnected(){

             Log.d("Log", "Came in onConnected state from C++ " ); // This log is printed and works fine
             pc.setSdp();    // This is where it fails, it just doesn't find pc 


       }
```

Any ideas what I can do to have access to that pc variable in the callback ? I already tried storing it as a static variable and accessing it later but that doesn't work either.

Edit :

Logcat : http://paste2.org/A0ea06wK

Edit 2:

So I figured what I was doing wrong, I had a service and an AIDL so there were 2 different process thus the variables were null no matter what.

I still don't know how to access the variables of one process after I recieve a callback from the other process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned, the actual problem was me trying to access variables across processes. So I eventually solved the problem by using aidl callback mechanism. This let me get access to the UI objects from the background service usign the listener mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
initialize(new MainActivity());
```

write this

```
initialize(this);
```

Two things to note :

- it's very bad practice to create an Activity instance yourself.
- when you do `new MainActivity()` the `onCreate(...)` is not called and so `pc` is never initialized.

> > I even tried passing context/activity instance to C++ code but that doesn't work either

What's going on ? same NPE ? Is yes, it's probably that the native code callback `onConnected()` during the execution of `initialize()`. So just do this :

```
PeerConnectionFactory factory = new PeerConnectionFactory();
MediaConstraints pcConstraints = sdpMediaConstraints;
pcConstraints.optional.add(
new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("RtpDataChannels", "true"));
pcConstraints.optional.add(
new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement", "true"));

pc = factory.createPeerConnection(iceServers, pcConstraints, pcObserver); // This is where pc is assigned 

initialize(this);   // This is native function which takes the object name
```

Comment: please post the logcat

Comment: Added logcat to the post

Comment: This is all you have in logcat ? (the stack seems truncate). And very simple check : are you sure that `factory.createPeerConnection` NEVER return null ?

Comment: Yes I am sure pc is not null as I use that pc variable for other functions and they work perfectly. The stack has a lot of unwanted logs from the Resip c++ code. Also I have tried to initialize the app through a service. Yopu want me to create pastes of my relevant classes and post them for you ?